# Group paths by starting node to print - Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop3

I am fairly new to the Gremlin language and still learning its basics. I would like to group my outputs from my source node.

As an example, take the ToyGraph example, created using
`graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()`. Suppose for each software, I would like to calculate the mean age of its creaters, I would have to do something like
`g.V('software').in('created').mean()`, however this would give me the mean of all creaters of all softwares, how would I get an output of the form:
{softA : 31.0, softB : 40.6, ...}.
I have tried the `group` clause and `aggregrate`, but not really sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great example of when you would want to look at using a [project()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#project-step) step.  A project() step will create a map of values with the specified labels starting from the current location in the graph.  In this case we find all `software` vertices and then `project()` the name and ages out from each `software` vertex.  I put an example of this below which also includes all the `age` values it found to show that it is calculating the `mean()` correctly.

```
g.V().hasLabel('software').project('software', 'ages', 'mean_age').
by().
by(__.in('created').values('age').fold()).
by(__.in('created').values('age').mean())

==>[software:v[3],ages:[29,32,35],mean_age:32.0]
==>[software:v[5],ages:[32],mean_age:32.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use `group` for this. The first part of the query finds anything that is software and the group then calculates the mean age of the creators.

```java
gremlin>    g.V().hasLabel('software').
......1>          group().
......2>            by('name').
......3>            by(__.in('created').values('age').mean()) 

==>[ripple:32.0,lop:32.0]
```

To verify we got the correct answers:

```java
gremlin>    g.V().hasLabel('software').
......1>          group().
......2>            by('name').
......3>            by(__.in('created').values('age').fold())    
   
==>[ripple:[32],lop:[29,32,35]]
```